# App Store Connect - French Government ANSSI Regulation

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When submitting my App to App Store Connect, regarding the export compliances i had to send a filled out the form 'crypto_declaration-demande_autorisation_operations_annexe1.pdf' and send it to the email address 'controle@ssi.gouv.fr'

Do you know, how long it will take to get it processed?
Currently I excluded France in my app, in order to not get blocked by updating my app.

https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-app-information/overview-of-export-compliance/

And maybe also, how much it will cost.

Answer (score 0):

According to the E-Mail that i got as response, they can take up to two month in order to process this request.